# Windows phone how to show elements beyond the screen size

Tags: windows-phone-7

Windows phone Application. I set the layout width 960px with two 480px StackPanel. First I can see the first StackPanel and I want to transfer the Layout to see the second StackPanel but I found nothing in the second StackPanel

Answer (score 0):

1) Put the two stack panels in a parent stackpanel and arrange them horizontally and add the parent stackpanel to a `scrollviewer` with `horizontal scroll` as on. Then you can scroll horizontally.

2) You can also use `Pivot/Panorama` for such scenarios.